# Resizing Keynote Slides

Tags: keynote

I received a 4:3 Keynote presentation that had been changed to 16:9 (adding white bars to left and right) and then changed back to 4:3 (adding white bars to top and bottom).

Now all my content is basically shrunk to 75% of it's original size with a white box around everything.

Is there a way to resize the slides with out resizing the content or resize all the content up? (I have 84 slides, I can't do it one by one)

Comment: Could you provide a sample few slides? I could try some scripting maybe…

Comment: @grgarside [Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gSn-4sC4-BLU54Z2Vna2dOTnc/edit?usp=sharing) a sample I threw onto Google Drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible in the app. You can notify Apple that you would like this feature implemented using their Keynote feedback page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/keynote.html